# How to handle web tasks normally handled by clicking with Python?

Tags: python

I decided to try to do some projects in Python but so far, I've only been doing things which you can do without simulating actions of a human, for the lack of a better term. Now, I wanted to create a script that would take a list of movies and the score 1-10 I've given each and then rate each of these movies on iMDB. The problem is, I have no idea how such things are usually handled.

Normally, to rate a movie you have to log in to your account and then search for the movie and manually click the appropriate number of stars. I surely can handle the searching part and parsing data from the file with movie list but how can I make the script do something that would result in rating a movie? I only know how to do it by creating a script that would actually perform those tasks in the browser (i.e. by taking a screenshot, parsing it, looking for the rating stars and manually clicking it) but it would take a lot of time and be very prone to errors such as browser errors or timeouts.

How are such tasks (doing something requiring action on the web rather than just mining data and processing it offline) usually tackled?

Comment: Use Selenium: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Comment: Use an [API](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I've already looked for an API but each one, the one you linked to included, regretfully only provides data collecting mechanisms but nothing working in the opposite direction like actually rating a movie with a given account information :(

Comment: @Straightfw My suggestion was posted as a comment because I didn't think that a single sentence was enough to constitute a "proper" answer, but if Selenium solves your problem then I'd recommend that you accept the [answer posted by Mo H.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29287133/4200092) below.

Comment: @GoBusto btw, sorry if I sniped your answer, I just thought it could be explained further in an answer format, as the OP probably didn't know what WebDriver was.

Comment: @MoH. That's OK. Your answer provides a fair bit more detail than my two-word comment, and anyway: [*"Reputation is a fun side-show, but the main event here is obviously sharing knowledge."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8092)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need Selenium Webdriver. Its a library that allows you to manipulate (or drive) a web browser using code. Id recommend going to this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (provided by GoBusto), and [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) one for a brief introduction to specflow and having a look at the selenium tag on SO. Its a great tool to learn, but has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Thank you. But does that mean I have to actually have the browser fired on a physical machine and it manipulates my cursor or can it just simulate it so that I can have the script running in the background while I'm doing different things?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't control your cursor, It runs using a separate browser (chromedriver.exe for chrome for example) or directly from Firefox. A web browser IS loaded, but it can be run in the background so it doesn't interfere with you using your computer